# non-type template parameter vs function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, arguments

I wrote a trivial example, which is somehow compiles.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int A>
void func()
{
    cout << 1 + A << endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    // I can not even use this strange func()
    int a = 1; func(a); // this does not compile
    func(1);            // this does not compile as well 
    return 0;
}
```

This example frustrates me a lot:

First, I gave non-type template parameter to template, but did not provide any parameters (in parentheses) to function itself. Looks like template parameter becomes the function parameter, but why?

Second, even though it compiles, I can not find a way to use this template, see my comments in `main`.

And third, what is the reason for existence of template functions with non-type template parameter of integral type? How is it any different from having a regular function?

Comment: BTW don't use endl. It's slow because you have to flush the buffer every time you use it. "\n" is faster and understood by programmers of most languages, not only C++

Answer (score 1):

`int A` is not a function parameter, it's a template parameter. `func` takes no arguments and you instantiate/call it like this:

```
func<1>(); // compile-time constant needed
```

Please review C++ function templates. You can't use template parameters in the way you want.

On the other hand, having a type template parameter and one function parameter:

```
template <typename A>
void func(A a)
{
    cout << 1 + a << endl;
}
```

will make your program valid. Maybe that's what you wanted.

**Edit:**

To your request, here's a usage of such non-type function template parameter:

```
template <size_t S>
void func(const int (&array)[S])
{
    cout << "size of the array is: " << S << endl;
}
```

or `std::array` version:

```
template <size_t S>
void func(std::array<int, S> const& array)
{
    cout << "size of the array is: " << S << endl;
}
```

`S` here is deduced to the size of the passed array.

Comment: **LogicStuff**, I agree with what you've said. But how is the template argument allowed to be used within a template function definition, like if it was a function argument? I mean those `cout << 1 + A << endl;` line.

Comment: By doing `func<1>`, a function will be instantiated at compile-time like this: `cout << 1 + 1 << endl;`. It's compile-time matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you give a scenario, when template functions with non-type template parameter of integer type could be useful?